# 3D Sphere Effect in Flutter

Tags: flutter

I want to create a view like below.

[image: sphere]

I tried adding a RadialGradient but it doesn't exact like this image.

```
Container(
      height: 50,
      width: 50,
      decoration: const BoxDecoration(
        color: Color(0xff2DD485),
        shape: BoxShape.circle,
        gradient: RadialGradient(colors: [Color(0xff42CF8C), Color(0xff1DAE69)], center: Alignment(0, -0.7), stops: [0, 1]),
      ),
      child: const Icon(Icons.done_rounded, color: Colors.white),
    )
```

Comment: You could simply use a svg/jpg image or a rive/flair image would also be as good because with code it would be much harder. If still you want to try it with code then try `CustomPainter`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

a bit ugly, but do the trick:

```dart
child: ClipRRect(
  borderRadius: const BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(25)),
  child: Container(
    height: 50,
    width: 50,
    color: const Color(0xff2DD485),
    child: Stack(
      alignment: AlignmentDirectional.center,
      children: [
        Positioned(
          bottom: 22,
          child: Container(
            height: 50,
            width: 50,
            decoration: const BoxDecoration(
              color: Color(0xff56dc9d),
              shape: BoxShape.circle,
            ),
          ),
        ),
        const Icon(Icons.done_rounded, color: Colors.white),
      ],
    ),
  ),
)
```